# Stuck on algebra question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If

> $a + b = -2$

and

> $a^2 = b^2 - 16$

find the value of

> $4(a-b)$

Comment: Recall that $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: Hint : You know $a+b$ and can easily determine $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$

Comment: You do know that you can enclose entire expressions between dollar signs, right? `$a^2 = b^2 - 16$` gives $a^2 = b^2-16$, which looks a lot better than $a^2$=$b^2$-16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a^2=b^2-16\iff a^2-b^2=-16\to(a+b)(a-b)=-16 \text{ (By DOTS})$$
$$\to-2(a-b)=-16\to(a-b)=8\to4(a-b)=32$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Compute the value of $\:4(a^2-b^2)$ first.

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$
$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)=-16\\
\frac{\cancel{(a+b)}(a-b)}{\cancel{(a+b)}}=\frac{-16}{-2}\\
(a-b)=8\\\vdots$$